# Functional Analysis - exercice bachman

Tags: functional-analysis

Please help with this question of the book BACHMAN, G. Functional Analysis, pg 257, ex 4.

If ${A_n}$ is a sequence in $L(X,Y)$, where $X$ is a Banach space. Such that $A_n \rightharpoonup A$, then show that exists an $M$ such that $\|A_n\|\leq M$, for all $n$.

Thanks very much

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please update your question with information about what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that weakly convergent sequences are bounded and uniform boundedness principle to arrive at your claim.